# NgModel shows only one value

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]
[image]
Hello I am calling a column values from db (interest) and i want to pass them with NgModel to ion-toggles. As you may see on the screenshot 3 values are returning (Painting, Illustration, Graphic Design) but only 1 (Painting) is true (toggle on right side)

Html

```
<ion-list >
    <ion-list-header>
    I am Interested in...
    </ion-list-header><div><br /></div>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Painting</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="gold" [ngModel]="interest=='Painting' ? true:false" (ionChange)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Painting')"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Graphic Design</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="tertiary" [ngModel]="interest=='Graphic Design' ? true:false" (ionChange)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Graphic Design')"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Illustration</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="danger" [ngModel]="interest=='Illustration' ? true:false" (ionChange)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Illustration')"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Sculpture</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="success" [ngModel]="interest=='Sculpture' ? true:false" (ionChange)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Sculpture')"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Literature</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="danger" [ngModel]="interest=='Literature' ? true:false" (ionChange)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Literature')"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Theater</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="dark" [ngModel]="interest=='Theater' ? true:false" (ionChange)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Theater')"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Film</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle color="warning" [ngModel]="interest=='Film' ? true:false" (ionChange)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Film')"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
```

component.ts

```
export class CreativeSettingsPage implements OnInit {
  creativeInterests: any=[];
  creative: any= {};
  userDetails: any = {};
  interest:any=[];
  constructor(
    public userData: UserData
  ) {
    this.userDetails = this.userData.getUserData();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.creativeInsterestSet();
  }

  creativeInsterestSet() {
    this.userData.creativeInterests(this.userDetails.uid).pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
            if (data.success) {
                this.creativeInterests = data.creativeInterests;
                this.creativeInterests.filter(item =>  {
                  this.interest=item.interest;
                 console.log( this.interest);
              });
               
            }
        })
    ).subscribe()
}
```

Comment: It's true only for Painting because you are using one variable for all interest in your filter method (that's why only latest value from array is set to true). You should change it from equal this.interest = item.interest to e. g. this.interest.push(item.interest) and after that change logic in your ngModels in html (or you can use creativeInterests variable which is array of your interest)

Comment: I shared new photo to see now. Change logic?

Comment: Yes, because now you have array of strings, so ngModel="interest=='Painting? true : false'" can't work.

Comment: @ Mateusz Ścigała
 I tried changing NgModel in every way. Can you share the answer?

Comment: e. g. like that: <ion-toggle [ngModel]="isInterestInArray('Painting')"></ion-toggle>
and in ts file isInterestInArray(type: string): boolean { return this.creativeInterests.indexOf(type) !== -1; }

Answer (score 0):

You should use ngModel with just a variable name such as:

```
<element [ngModel]="variableName"></element>
```

and then in your component assign a value to this `ngModel` based on some logic:

```
assignLogic() {
    if (otherVariable === "Theater") {
        variableName = "Theater";
    }
}
```

This will update your display!

Comment: so, this.interest.push(item.interest)
                 console.log( this.interest);
                 if (this.interest === "Painting") {
                  this.crinterest = "Painting";
              }.  and [NgModel] = "crinterest"  doesn't work

Comment: So, each toggle will have a different variable? No

Comment: Yes, each toggle a different variable name